# Find the exact hexcode for the color in image for Android

Tags: android, background-color, color-picker

I am trying to develop application based on the GUI snapshot provided by client. Some of the image provided have to blend with back ground color . I was wondering if there is any tool that can determine color from the image and is accurate.

I tried color picker app from android, but color code does not reflect the same color while launching app. Any recommendation of using any tools / app or tricks ?

Comment: your best bet is to request for the actual images (as psd or layered png) from the client. i wouldn't recommend trying to color picker a flattened image if you're aiming for exact color reproduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find color pickers online... That's the only way I think. Then I aim the pen to the images to determine it's hexcode.

Comment: accepting this answer since online color picker worked for me , unlike the app. this is what I used for reference to any other vistor to this question : http://html-color-codes.info/colors-from-image/